# How to select the data based on the upper ID when ID of parent object is matched with child object Product ID in php?

Tags: php, api

Problem: I want to get data of child object based on the id of the parent object. As in parent object the id is 1 and in the child object there are more than 1 object that is based on the Product ID . So the value selection of child object is based upon parent id. There are 8 main id objects and each have child objects.

My question is when I click on the button of the parent ID the data of the that parent ID matching to product ID and display the only data of the selected parent ID?

```
foreach($response2 as $value)
            {
              $id=$value['id'];
               var_dump($id);
              // echo "<div>
              // <img src='$value['thumbnails']['thumbnailLink']' alt='Image'/>
              // </div>";
              // echo($value['thumbnails']);

              foreach($value['thumbnails'] as $value2){
                echo $value2['modelLink'];
                echo '<br>';
              }
              echo '<br>';
              
              // echo '<br>';
            }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `My question is`...unfortunately the phrase you've written after that is not actually a question. Putting a ? at the end of a statement doesn't magically turn it into a real question. Please clarify your post.

Comment: Also, as per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code or data. This inforation is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: It would also help to have a worked example showing exactly what data you want to return in response to a specific click. And we don't really know what your buttons are (since we can't see them - that's where a screenshot _would_ be useful) or how that relates to the short snippet of PHP you've provided, or to the data. The whole thing is very unclear.